# wxwidget build failed - windows - mingw - mingw32-make: *** [..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxmsw313u_gcc_custom.dll] Error 1

Tags: wxwidgets, mingw32

I was trying use build `wxWidgets-3.1.3` with `MinGW-W64` on a `x64` windows machine.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44416220/10305444) thread, which lead me to download and building. So I installed it and some youtube videos said I need to build it now. So navigate to the installed folder and gave this command :

**`mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1`**.

It took almost half an hour and now it's giving me error saying :

```
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile.gcc:5329: recipe for target '..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxmsw313u_gcc_custom.dll' failed
mingw32-make: *** [..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxmsw313u_gcc_custom.dll] Error 1
```

Here is the full log file :

https://pastebin.com/zxeHhF6K

MinGW configuration :

```
Version : 8.1.0
Architecture : x86_64
Threads : posix
Exceptions : seh
Build version : 0
```

How can I solve this? I'm using CLion, is there any other short or easy way?

Comment: could you please try with just `mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release`? Also which version of MinGW do you use?

Comment: version is  8.1.0, btw I have added full config in the que

Comment: did you try to rebuild with the command I suggested?

Comment: That command exited without error, a few minute ago. but I can't still configure it in CLion, so is it done ?

Comment: if it finishes without errors than everything is good. You can check it by doing this: `cd samples\minimal && mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release && minimal`. Configuring CLion is completely different topic. You need to explain what you are doing there and how do you configure it.

Comment: BTW, why did you decide to build a release version of the library? You SHOULD start with `mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=debug`.

Comment: [here](https://gist.github.com/maifeeulasad/28ff22f647d1a08b85823f3d892e7e97) is my CLion's makefile ... i followed [this](https://youtu.be/FgAaiBg4wEE?t=266) tutorial... i just searched how to use wxWidgets in CLion and it came..

Comment: you should configure the project in CLion the usual way - by adding the include and library path and the appropriate libraries to link with.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant error is

```
..\..\lib\gcc_dll/libwxexpat.a(wxexpat_xmlparse.o):xmlparse.c:(.text+0x337d): undefined reference to `_imp__rand_s'
```

and it's very strange because MinGW-w64 8.1 is definitely supposed to have `rand_s()`. Are you sure you're using the right compiler? I.e. what does `g++ -v` give you if you run it from the same command prompt?

My only hypothesis is that it's some different (and much older) compiler and the solution would be to just use the right one instead.

Also, the next time you could use `-j4` option with make if you have at least 4 logical CPUs in your machine (and chances are you do nowadays), to significantly speed up the build.

Answer (score 0):

Looking back in my notes I once had an issue with missing rand_s() when building glib2 on a certain MinGW build.

I was able to fix it then by adding this at the top of the C file that called this function:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int rand_s (unsigned int* r)
{
  static int srand_called = 0;
  if (!srand_called) {
    srand(time(0));
    srand_called++;
  }
  if (r)
    *r = rand();
  return 0;
}
```

In your case that would be in `xmlparse.c`.